# Hay forma de que Exception_handler evite que se detenga la aplicación

Tags: genexus

Cuando leí en la ayuda sobre la regla **Exception_handler** pensé que evitaría tener que escribir en código externo el *Catch/Try*, pero por lo que veo lo único que permite es, por ejemplo, llamar a un proc para que guarde un log sobre el error.
Hay forma para que la app continúe, para que funcione como un catch/try y no precisar escribir código .Net o Java?

Answer (score 1):

Esto te puede ayudar Error_Handler

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6853,Error_Handler%20Rule

Saludos

Comment: Hola Leo. El Error_Handler es para errores de SQL. Yo pregunto por la regla Exception_handler https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?44808,Exception_Handler+Rule